# iOS 11 Webview remote debugging

Tags: safari, remote-debugging, wkwebview, ios11

I am trying to debug a WKWebview using Safari 10.1.1 .

I am able to do so successfully when I install my app on an iOS10 device but if I do so on an iOS11-Beta2 device it will not appear under the develop menu.

Is there a way to do so for iOS11 ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Safari technology preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/)

You'll need this to get Safari to pickup your iOS 11 device

Comment: Any idea if it's possible to use the new "connect via network" option in iOS 11/Xcode 9 to remote debug a web app? I can't see my device in Safari's Develop menu so I'm guessing not, unfortunately.

Comment: Looks like network debugging has been added to Release 37 (Safari 11.1, WebKit 12605.1.2)!